# Rails one-to-many relationship - keeping order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many

Consider this code:

```
class Sheet
    has_many :songs
end

class Song
    belongs_to :sheet
end

sheet = Sheet.find(1)
sheet.songs << Song.find(5)
sheet.songs << Song.find(10)
sheet.songs << Song.find(8)
```

Now the problem here is that when I run the code below, it returns me a list of songs for that sheet BUT they are not in the same order I added them in (5,10,8). It actually gives me the songs ordered by `name`.

```
songs = Sheet.find(1).songs
```

How can I keep the initial order of the songs?

Comment: you could also `songs = Sheet.find(1).songs.order("id asc")` or `songs = Sheet.find(1).songs.sort_by(&:id)`

Comment: @house9 I don't want to order by `id`. I want to keep the original order, the order it was added in.

Comment: ah yes, then you will need an additional model as `@CrazyVipa` suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a default order, you can do a few things.

Option a)

```
class Sheet
    has_many :songs, :order => 'songs.id DESC'
end
```

Options b)

```
class Song
    belongs_to :sheet
    default_scope :order => 'songs.id DESC'
end
```

I would not suggest doing default scope as it tends to cause issues with more associations.

---

Sorry, I think I read that wrong. If you ment keep the order to which it was added to the Sheet model, you would need a pivot table of some nature -- creating a has_many :through

It would turn into a:

```
class Sheet
    has_many :songs, :through => :sheet_songs, :order => 'sheet_songs.created_at DESC'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe store a timestamp, and order the results according to the time that they were entered... Im not sure its the smartest way buy...